# GStreamer "SimpleMovieDemo" bug on win x64

Tags: matlab, gstreamer, psychtoolbox

Movies aren't played. Matlab crushed even when I tried to run "SimpleMovieDemo".

I've done all recommendations suggested when running on Windows in this post:
https://github.com/Psychtoolbox-3/Psychtoolbox-3/issues/234.
I use "matlab.exe -nojvm", and tried many combinations of java, GStreamer and Matlab versions.

I still get this error when simply running "SimpleMovieDemo":

```
PTB-ERROR: Due to failed GStreamer initialization, the movie playback engine is disabled for this session.

Error in function OpenMovie:    Usage error
GStreamer initialization failed due to library loading problems. Aborted.
Error using Screen
Usage:

[ moviePtr [duration] [fps] [width] [height] [count] [aspectRatio]]=Screen('OpenMovie', windowPtr, moviefile [, async=0] [, preloadSecs=1] [, specialFlags1=0][, pixelFormat=4][,
maxNumberThreads=-1][, movieOptions]);

Error in SimpleMovieDemo (line 49)
    movie = Screen('OpenMovie', win, moviename);
```

Please help me display movies via Matlab PTB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tl;dr: Reinstall GStreamer, but pick "Custom installation" (Don't use "complete" or "regular" options!) on installation, then pick all the components options manually. After that, "SimpleMovieDemo" will work as expected via "Matlab.exe -nojvm".

It took some time until I found this little hiding solution under "help gstreamer", but under the header "Apple OSX", but it works like a charm on Windows 10 x64:

> When the installer asks you to select the components it should install,
>     select a "Custom installation" (instead of a "Basic installation" or such).
>     Then, if you chose a "Custom installation" in the displayed check list of packages
>     to install, select *all* components manually, if you want support for all
>     video formats and all functionality. Without this, many popular video
>     formats like H264 video will not play at all, or video recording / video
>     capture and similar functions may not work. In fact, even our own demos,
>     e.g., SimpleMovieDemo *will fail* if you don't have all codecs installed!
>     -> If SimpleMovieDemo doesn't work, then the most likely cause is that
>     you didn't select all GStreamer packages for installation, so restart the
>     installer and repeat installation with the full set of packages.

Answer (score 0):

Actually pick "Custom installation" doesn't work for my psychotoolbox.
I also met the same problem with you. My psychotoolbox version was 3.0.15 at that time and looked for answer on the google.

I found the url: https://github.com/Psychtoolbox-3/Psychtoolbox-3/wiki/FAQ#how-to-resolve-gstreamer-problems. It said "*On Windows: Upgrade to Psychtoolbox 3.0.16 with GStreamer 1.16.0 MSVC or later and retry*."

Then I upgrade my Psychtoolbox to the latest version of 3.0.17 and download the GStreamer 1.18.1 **runtime MSVC**(Not the development version or MingW, they won't work). I choose the typical installation for my GStreamer and then test SimpleMovieDemo on matlab.

Finally, it worked. I actually don't know the reason but hope my experience can help you.